# Receiving Mockito UnfinishedStubbingException for doNothing.when clause in Android Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, powermock

Firstly, my setup is RXJava 1, Retrofit 2 and I'm using Java 7.

I have a method that, when it is called, will set an atomic boolean to true.

That method then calls a retrofit API.

Upon completion, timeout etc... the atomic boolean is reset to false.

So, I would therefore like to uni test that when I call my method, the Atomic Boolean is set to true.

So, I do the following:

```
    assertFalse(orderUseCase.isOrderInProcess());

    orderUseCase.execute(id, orderWrapper, ts);

    assertTrue(orderUseCase.isOrderInProcess());
```

Test that the boolean is false.
Execute my use case
Test that the boolean is true.

Now, in order to perform the last test I need to ensure the API does nothing when it is called (the execute method will call the retrofit API.

To try and doNothing I am using the following line at the start of my test case.

```
doNothing().when(orderAPI.orderComplete(anyString(), any(OrderWrapper.class)));
```

I am however receiving the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.tfds.xms.unit_test.SingleTest.TestAtomicBooleanLocked(SingleTest.java:90)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

From reading where other people had a similar issue, the answers were suggesting that their 'when' line was calling another Mock (which I don't believe I am doing) or that they hadn't done the 'PrepareForTest' step which I have done. I am however wondering if what is in my prepareForTest section is correct or not...

Incidentally I understand that the error is pointing me to add a 'thenReturn' but that would mean that the API 'does' something and would consequently cause the Atomic Boolean to unlock again, which is not what I want..

Any help is very much appreciated.

My full test case is:

```
@RunWith(TestRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({OrderApiService.class, OrderUseCase.class})
public class SingleTest {

    @Rule
    public RxJavaResetRule pluginsReset = new RxJavaResetRule();

    private OrderApiService orderAPI;
    private OrderUseCase orderUseCase;
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Mock App app;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        orderAPI = mock(OrderApiService.class);

        orderRepository = new OrderRepository(app, orderAPI);

        orderUseCase = new OrderUseCase(orderRepository);

    }

    @Test
    public void TestAtomicBooleanLocked() throws Exception {

        doNothing().when(orderAPI.orderComplete(anyString(), any(OrderWrapper.class)));

        String id = "5";

        Order order = new Order();

        OrderWrapper orderWrapper = new orderWrapper(order);

        TestSubscriber<GenericResponse> ts = new TestSubscriber<GenericResponse>();

        assertFalse(orderUseCase.isOrderInProcess());

        orderUseCase.execute(id, orderWrapper, ts);

        assertTrue(orderUseCase.isOrderInProcess());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `doNothing()` method from `Mockito` works a bit different then the standalone `when()` method. You should be fine by just pushing the method call out of the `.doNothing()` like this:

```
doNothing().when(orderAPI)
    .orderComplete(anyString(), any(OrderWrapper.class));
```

Happy testing!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. In terms of resolving my issue, yes, that does it and thank you for that but... it then instead leads me to a different issue. Since this is an API call it would return something so can I not use doNothing in this case? Is there another way?

org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Only void methods can doNothing()!
Example of correct use of doNothing():
    doNothing().
    doThrow(new RuntimeException())
    .when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Above means:
someVoidMethod() does nothing the 1st time but throws an exception the 2nd time is called

Comment: I can see that 'when(spy.myMethod()).thenReturn(null)' seems to be the approach but.. can I use that with my API call above?